# What are docker child images

Tags: docker

What are docker child images and why can't I delete them?

I have been working with a Kali Linux image and I commit my changes and call it Kaliupdate1, make more changes and call it Kaliupdate2 and then I try to remove Kaliupdate1 but it doesn't work...

```
 docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
kaliupdate2         latest              e57f94c32fac        18 hours ago        2.25 GB
kaliupdate1         latest              16da215f736c        18 hours ago        1.12 GB
kaliupdate          latest              a841aa8bb8a9        19 hours ago        1.07 GB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So from your question, assuming that your workflow has been to start a container, work interactively inside the container and then commit the changes to a new image, the answer is that what you're essentially doing is creating a new layer on top of the existing kali base image.

As such the full stack of layers are required to operate.  This doesn't mean that the disk space taken is 2.25+1.12+1.07 however as Docker shares the lower layers.

That said this isn't a great way to create Docker images, as doing things like `chown` and `mv` can leave redundant files in the image.

A better way is to create a new Dockerfile based on the original kali image (using `FROM kali:latest` in the Dockerfile) and then make the changes you want in the Dockerfile and execute a build , to give you the final image.

There's more information on Docker's website [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Comment: Thank you Rory, I will review this doc.